# redux toolkit reducer with multiple parameters? redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Given this

```
export const slice = createSlice({
    name: 'reducer',
    initialState: {

    },
    reducers: {
       test: (state, action) => {
           console.log(action.payload) // 1
       } 

    },

})
```

then I run this

```
dispatch(test(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
```

`action.payload` is only the 1st parameter. How do I get the other 6?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read the relevant [documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction#using-prepare-callbacks-to-customize-action-contents)

> By default, the generated action creators accept a **single** argument, which becomes `action.payload`. This requires the caller to construct the entire payload correctly and pass it in.

So you could do call the action with

```
dispatch(test([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]))
```

this way, the payload will now be the array you passed.

---

If, however, you need to be able to call it with multiple arguments, you can use the [`prepare`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#defining-action-contents-with-prepare-callbacks) callback

> If you want to add a `meta` or `error` property to your action, **or customize the `payload` of your action**, you have to use the `prepare` notation.

```js
export const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'reducer',
  initialState: {

  },
  reducers: {
    test: {
      reducer(state, action){
        console.log(action.payload) // 1
      },
      prepare(...arguments){
        return {
          payload: arguments;
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

This way, your original way of calling the action will again result in a payload of an array which will contain all the arguments you passed, regardless of their number.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, We can send multiple parameters in redux reducer but after wrapping inside single object. Single object parameter can be array or JSON object.

```
// as an array
dispatch(test(["first","second","third"]));
// as a JSON object
dispatch(test({ first:1, second:2, third:3 }));
```

your result will be like this.

```
export const slice = createSlice({
name: 'reducer',
initialState: {

},
reducers: {
   test: (state, action) => {
     console.log(action.payload) // ["first","second","third"]
     // or in case of JSON object
     console.log(action.payload) // { first:1, second:2, third:3 }
   } 

},

})
```

Comment: this answer is what i was looking for! Thanks!